# How to do a group StructureDescription in Sage?

Tags: group-theory, sagemath

In Sage I executed the following commands:

```
 F.<x, y> = FreeGroup()
 G=F / [x^2*y^-1, x^3*y^2, x*y*x^-1*y^-1]
```

Now G is isomorphic to C7. In GAP I could check this with the StructureDescription command, how can I check this in Sage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
sage: G.as_permutation_group().structure_description()
'C7'
```

The function should probably be exposed in G directly, however.

Nathann

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Is this documented?

Comment: I do not know if it is what you ask, but the function's documentation is there: http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup.html#sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup.PermutationGroup_generic.structure_description

Comment: I suspected as much but if you don't know it is there, it is hard to find. Unfortunately developers consider their job done when they completed the code and testing. But who will use their code if it is not -properly- documented with lots of examples? - Anyway, you might know the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086427/how-to-list-all-subgroups-of-a-n-abelian-group-with-sage

Comment: @NathannCohen: thanks for the link to its documentation in Sage. I was surprised to see "Requires the optional database_gap package" though, since `StructureDescription` is provided by the core GAP system.

Comment: ndroock1: you have no reason to accuse us of that, for we take documentation seriously. Why else do you think that I am here to answer your question ? This function should be exposed in F directly and not only in F.as_permutation_group(), it is true. I did not know, I only use permutation groups. Now, you have the choice to complain because of this problem you found in a software you got for free, or to come help us change it. Create a ticket, write a patch, and solve the problem you met. That's how Sage became what it is.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: could it be possible that having the smallgroups package installed makes a different wrt this function's output ? That could be a reason why this note is there, otherwise it should probably be removed indeed.

Comment: Nathan, Sage is an achievement of truly epic proportions. I am a developer myself, I made a general remark about the dilemma of dividing our time between coding new features, writing tests and documenting.

Comment: @ndroock1 - you are right, but I have to say that most people's time on Sage is quite limited, and so indeed many do consider their job done when they complete code and testing, as we require doctests for any given functionality.  The problem is that adding that to some general tutorial or such usually is enough more work that it is harder.  Thanks for uncovering this, by the way!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that one can try to convert such finitely presented groups into permutation groups, at which point one can compare them to most "standard" finite groups (using Gap behind the scenes).

```
sage: H = CyclicPermutationGroup(7)
sage: H.is_isomorphic(G.as_permutation_group())
True
```

Comment: This feels rather inefficient as it requires you to first guess the group.

Comment: Ah!  I see what you mean, I didn't know what `StructureDescription` did.

Comment: See http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/17573

Answer (score 1):

( I needed this answer -badly-, kept trying all day, got the answer now. )
Sage has no implementation of its own of StructureDescription so GAP must be used. ( I don't know how it works internally but this command gives the required result.

```
  G.gap().StructureDescription()
```

Comment: Sage tries to build the car, not reinvent the wheel, so it is likely that robust existing functionality would be wrapped anyway.  If you would find this particularly useful to have with a Sage command and not via the Gap interface (as you did here), let us know!  See also my answer.